# Google Chart APIs for plotting data in local machine

Tags: scripting, desktop-application, google-visualization, time-tracking, web-scripting

**Preface:**

I am a system programmer (who has just started his career as a S/W Engineer), so not very good @ web scripting languages, though I have just started learning them.

**Problem Synopsis:**

I want to write an app that keeps track of what I am doing and records it allowing me to analyse my time spending pattern and could help me analyse whenever I want.

**Problem Description:**

My plan is to write an app that sits in the background and keeps track of active window on my desktop (every second) and stores this data in a SQLite database. But to be more appealing (As I want to share this app with others), I want to have a feature where the user can analyse data recorded between any period of his interest. For this I want the user to be able to generate charts and graphs using the recorded data.

For this I thought of using browser for UI and Google Visualization APIs for plotting work. So, is it possible to use Google Visualization APIs to plot local data? if so, plz guide me on how to continue... (As told before, I am a system programmer, C programmer to be specific, who has just started learning web scripting in free time)

**Reasons for these decisions:**

*(1) App that records what I am doing will be in C/C++* - B'coz I am system programmer and am very comfortable with them. And can get it done easily and quickly.

*(2) SQLite* - Very small and can easily be embedded in my app, and is Open Source. And I think many web scripting langs like PHP, python have interfaces to access SQLite DB.

*(3) Browser for UI* - Hope it will be easy for user to use browser, and I will not have much to do regarding UI. As main UI will be browser and Google Visualization APIs will do plotting. All I might have to do is write few lines of script (Am I right here on the last point???)

Comment on my design decision and any tutorials(or pointers) which teaches me on how to do this will be highly appreciated...

**Thank You**

***MicroKernel :)***

**PS:** Idea inspired by **Nathan Baulch's reply** to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161590/how-do-you-track-your-time

@**Nathan Baulch**, Thank you so much for such a brilliant idea. \m/

Answer (score 0):

I would embed browser to app (you want to write in C#)

and use jquery plotting as chart. You will find more info here: http://www.flotcharts.org/